# How do I format data for POST via ajax on jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I think I have misunderstood something to do with POSTing data via jQuery. Whichever way I add the vars to `data`, I end up with something that just fails. How do I correctly pass my vars into the bit marked "[THIS BIT]"?

```
  jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: vars.path,
        data: [THIS BIT],
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            /* do something amazing */
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            /* do something amazing */
        }
    });
```

Things I tried before I figured it out:

```
data: text,
```

then

```
data: {url:text},
```

(that was not good)

```
$idata = '{url:'+text+'}';
...
data: idata,
```

Still no.

```
var idata = {};
idata['url'] = text;
idata['example'] = 'text';
idata['foo'] = 'bar';
...
data: idata,
```

As per comments what I needed was

```
data: JSON.stringify(idata),
```

Comment: your request specify json, so just json encode your object `JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: "*Whichever way I add the vars to `data`*"... you haven't provided a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the community to see how you've previously attempted this - consider adding it for more robust suggestions that can either build off your attempt or point out the issues with it.

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is an object like

```
var obj = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
}
```

then ajax should be like

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        /* do something amazing */
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, status) {
        /* do something amazing */
    }
});
```